# Bloated Cache Storage... How to inspect or browse the "Cache Storage" generated by service workers?

Tags: single-page-application, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, cachestorage, mobify-js

We are currently working with an agency that have built our new eCommerce website in PWA on the mobify platform.

Our site performance is currently bad and i was brought into the project to help as a Product Owner.

I have noticed that the cache storage gets bloated pretty quickly. After navigating the website for a couple of minutes, my cache storage can reach up to 3GB and the site becomes very unresponsive.

What i don't find normal is that our cache gets up to 500mb after a page load...

How would I be able to inspect or browse the cache storage to pinpoint what would cause the cache to be so bloated?

I haven't work on react/pwa before, it's all new to me for the moment.

Any pointers on this would be very much appreciated!

Cheers!
John

[Cache Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkJLL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Cache Storage" menu and you can select the different caches to see what's being stored.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome DevTools showing "cache storage' menu]